# How to implement this type specific object generator without using C++0x auto

Tags: c++, templates, boost, c++11

I have a templated function where the templated parameter is a functor.  I want to generate some internal variables, specific to a particular quality function, to be used by other template functions called from this functor.  so I have experimented with the auto keyword and it seems to work

```
template<typename QF>
float find_optimal_partition_louvain_with_gain(QF quality_function) {
    auto internal_variables = gen(quality_function);
    float result = do_some_work(internal_variables);
    ...
    return result;
}

struct internals_for_linearised_functor {
    double x;
};

internals_for_linearised_functor gen(mynamespace::linearised_function &f) {
    linearised_internals internals;
    internals.x = 5;
    return internals;
}
```

With auto this seems to compile fine, which is pleasing.  I would like to try to stay within the current standard though to make my code more portable.  Is there a way this can be handled using the current standard, or is this something that BOOST_AUTO will be able to handle?  The general function I am trying to achieve is generate an object based on a on the type of templated paramater without actually passing the type of the new object into the function (i.e. inferring it)

Thanks

Comment: So there are lots of overloads of `gen`, returning different internals for different function types, and corresponding overloads of `do_some_work`? You could introduce a traits class template, so that each time someone overloads `gen`, they also add a template specialization `template<> class internals_type<mynamespace::linearised_function> { typedef internals_for_linearised_functor value; }`. Then use `typename internals_type<QF>::value internal_variables = ...`

Comment: Always when I see these kind of questions I wonder how OOP is more clear for the programmer. A type specific object generator templated function with functor argument. Really?

Comment: @nightcracker: I don't think this code has much to do with OOP. The OOP way would be to define an interface for quality functions, and I guess another for internal variables if those can't be made genuinely internal. Then use dynamic polymorphism everywhere, so `find_optimal_partition_louvain_with_gain` doesn't need to know the runtime type of the internal variables, it can just refer to it via the interface type.

Comment: @Steve Jessop: Oh, then I mean C++... eehm.. how do you call it? Logic? Keywords?

Comment: @nightcracker: generic programming, I suppose. My point is just that C++ introduces novel means of confusing your readers, not really present in pure OO languages ;-)

Comment: @Steve Jessop: I guess because english isn't my first language it seems much more daunting to me then to a native speaker.

Comment: @nightcracker: to be honest I think you need *templates* to be your first language for this to be entirely clear. Interesting point, though, I wonder whether duck-typing in general makes it harder to understand code in second languages. It might, if it requires you to interpret more from the names of things like parameters (and template parameters in C++), whose required interface/semantics often aren't explicitly defined anywhere. Subtleties of meaning could become important if the author isn't careful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work out of the box:

```
template<typename QF>
float find_optimal_partition_louvain_with_gain(QF quality_function) {
    return do_some_work(gen(quality_function));
}
```

If you need `internal_variables` to be around longer than for just one call, you can use another small function to deduce the type:

```
template<typename QF, typename T>
float find_optimal_partition_louvain_with_gain_detail(QF quality_function, T internal) {
    float result = do_some_work(internal);
    /* use internal and quality_function again here!.*/
    return result;
}


template<typename QF>
float find_optimal_partition_louvain_with_gain(QF quality_function) {
    return find_optimal_partition_louvain_with_gain_detail(
      quality_function,
      gen(quality_function)
    );
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: +1, Template Argument Deduction is the standard fallback for `auto`.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use `auto` in this case, you'll need to use some kind of meta-function (a function trait, perhaps) to get the return type of `gen`.

Boost has function traits, or you could implement a traits class specifically for your `QF` type. If it's a standard function object type, it should have a `result_type` typedef, which you can get at using `typedef typename QF::result_type result_type`

Answer (score 0):

Can you wrap `gen()` as static method inside a struct and then replace the `internal_variables` ? See the following modified code.

```
struct Generate
{
  static internals_for_linearised_functor s_Internals; // define somewhere
  static void gen(mynamespace::linearised_function &f)
  {
    linearised_internals internals;
    internals.x = 5;
    s_Internals = internals;
  }
 };
```

Now, in function `find_optimal_partition_louvain_with_gain`, you can first call `Generate::gen()` and then use, `Generate::s_Internals` instead of `internal_variables`.

This seems to be easier way to avoid knowing the type of `auto`.
Also, you can make `Generate` as `template<>` if needed.
For *thread safety* in above code, we can implement without `static` also.